# How count specific occurence of a variable through a conditional if-statement loop

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, count

I am trying to count the occurrences of some observations according to the value taken by the 'unimodal_preset' variable (which you might find in the dataset I let you attached below) and store them in a small table, built as follows:

```
tab <- matrix(rep(0, times= 16), ncol= 2, byrow=TRUE)
colnames(tab) <- c('congruent', 'incongruent')
rownames(tab) <- rep(c('written', 'spoken'), 4)
tab <- as.table(tab)
tab
```

I have prepared the following for loop:

```
for (i in rownames(tab)){
  for (j in colnames(tab)){
    
    if (di$unimodal_preset == 0 & di$cong_cond == 'congreunt' & di$presentation_mode == 'spoken'){
      tab[i,j] <- di %>% filter(cong_cond == 'congruent' & presentation_mode == 'spoken' & unimodal_preset == 0) %>%  summarise(n = n()) %>% as.data.frame()
      
    } else if (di$unimodal_preset == 0 & di$cong_cond == 'congreunt' & di$presentation_mode == 'written') {
      tab[i,j] <-  di %>% filter(cong_cond == 'congruent' & presentation_mode == 'written' & unimodal_preset == 0) %>%  summarise(n = n()) %>% as.data.frame()
      
      
    } else if (di$unimodal_preset == 0 & di$cong_cond == 'incongreunt' & di$presentation_mode == 'spoken') {
      tab[i,j] <-  di %>% filter(cong_cond == 'incongruent' & presentation_mode == 'spoken' & unimodal_preset == 0) %>% summarise(n = n()) %>% as.data.frame()
      
    } else if (di$unimodal_preset == 0 & di$cong_cond == 'incongreunt' & di$presentation_mode == 'written') {
      tab[i,j] <-  di %>% filter(cong_cond == 'incongruent' & presentation_mode == 'written' & unimodal_preset == 0) %>%  summarise(n = n()) %>% as.data.frame()
      
      
    } else if (di$unimodal_preset == 1 & di$cong_cond == 'congreunt' & di$presentation_mode == 'spoken') {
      tab[i,j] <-  di %>% filter(cong_cond == 'congruent' & presentation_mode == 'spoken' & unimodal_preset == 1) %>%  summarise(n = n()) %>% as.data.frame()
      
      
    } else if (di$unimodal_preset == 1 & di$cong_cond == 'congreunt' & di$presentation_mode == 'written') {
      tab[i,j] <-  di %>% filter(cong_cond == 'congruent' & presentation_mode == 'written' & unimodal_preset == 1) %>%  summarise(n = n()) %>% as.data.frame()
      
    } else if (di$unimodal_preset == 1 & di$cong_cond == 'incongreunt' & di$presentation_mode == 'spoken') {
      tab[i,j] <-  di %>% filter(cong_cond == 'incongruent' & presentation_mode == 'spoken' & unimodal_preset == 1) %>%  summarise(n = n()) %>% as.data.frame()
      
    } 
    
    else if  (di$unimodal == 1 & di$cong_cond == 'incongreunt' & di$presentation_mode == 'written'){
      tab[i,j] <-  di %>% filter(cong_cond == 'incongruent' & presentation_mode == 'written' & unimodal_preset == 1) %>%  summarise(n = n())%>% as.data.frame()

    }
    
  }
}

print(tab)
```

but unfortunately, it does not seem to work on my end. Could you please suggest a possible way through? Here is the dataset I have used

```
> dput(head(di, 150))
structure(list(cong_cond = c("congruent", "congruent", "congruent", 
"congruent", "congruent", "congruent", "congruent", "congruent", 
"congruent", "congruent", "congruent", "congruent", "congruent", 
"congruent", "congruent", "congruent", "congruent", "congruent", 
"congruent", "congruent", "congruent", "congruent", "congruent", 
"congruent", "congruent", "congruent", "congruent", "congruent", 
"congruent", "congruent", "congruent", "congruent", "congruent", 
"congruent", "congruent", "congruent", "congruent", "congruent", 
"congruent", "congruent", "congruent", "congruent", "congruent", 
"congruent", "congruent", "congruent", "congruent", "congruent", 
"congruent", "congruent", "congruent", "congruent", "congruent", 
"congruent", "congruent", "congruent", "congruent", "congruent", 
"congruent", "congruent", "congruent", "congruent", "congruent", 
"congruent", "congruent", "congruent", "congruent", "congruent", 
"congruent", "congruent", "incongruent", "incongruent", "incongruent", 
"incongruent", "incongruent", "incongruent", "incongruent", "incongruent", 
"incongruent", "incongruent", "incongruent", "incongruent", "incongruent", 
"incongruent", "incongruent", "incongruent", "incongruent", "incongruent", 
"incongruent", "incongruent", "incongruent", "incongruent", "incongruent", 
"incongruent", "incongruent", "incongruent", "incongruent", "incongruent", 
"incongruent", "incongruent", "incongruent", "incongruent", "incongruent", 
"incongruent", "incongruent", "incongruent", "incongruent", "incongruent", 
"incongruent", "incongruent", "incongruent", "incongruent", "incongruent", 
"incongruent", "incongruent", "incongruent", "incongruent", "incongruent", 
"congruent", "congruent", "congruent", "congruent", "congruent", 
"congruent", "congruent", "congruent", "congruent", "congruent", 
"congruent", "congruent", "congruent", "congruent", "congruent", 
"congruent", "congruent", "congruent", "congruent", "congruent", 
"congruent", "congruent", "congruent", "congruent", "congruent", 
"congruent", "congruent", "congruent", "congruent", "congruent", 
"congruent", "congruent"), presentation_mode = c("spoken", "spoken", 
"spoken", "spoken", "spoken", "spoken", "spoken", "spoken", "spoken", 
"spoken", "spoken", "spoken", "spoken", "spoken", "spoken", "spoken", 
"spoken", "spoken", "spoken", "spoken", "spoken", "spoken", "spoken", 
"spoken", "spoken", "spoken", "spoken", "spoken", "spoken", "spoken", 
"spoken", "spoken", "spoken", "spoken", "spoken", "written", 
"written", "written", "written", "written", "written", "written", 
"written", "written", "written", "written", "written", "written", 
"written", "written", "written", "written", "written", "written", 
"written", "written", "written", "written", "written", "written", 
"written", "written", "written", "written", "written", "written", 
"written", "written", "written", "written", "spoken", "spoken", 
"spoken", "spoken", "spoken", "spoken", "spoken", "spoken", "spoken", 
"spoken", "spoken", "spoken", "spoken", "spoken", "spoken", "spoken", 
"spoken", "spoken", "spoken", "spoken", "spoken", "spoken", "spoken", 
"spoken", "written", "written", "written", "written", "written", 
"written", "written", "written", "written", "written", "written", 
"written", "written", "written", "written", "written", "written", 
"written", "written", "written", "written", "written", "written", 
"written", "spoken", "spoken", "spoken", "spoken", "spoken", 
"spoken", "spoken", "spoken", "spoken", "spoken", "spoken", "spoken", 
"spoken", "spoken", "spoken", "spoken", "spoken", "spoken", "spoken", 
"spoken", "spoken", "spoken", "spoken", "spoken", "spoken", "spoken", 
"spoken", "spoken", "spoken", "written", "written", "written"
), unimodal_preset = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -150L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like `di %>% count(cong_cond, presentation_mode, unimodal_preset)` using `dplyr`?

Comment: It's hard to work out exactly what you want, but try `table(di)` and/or `as.data.frame(table(di))` and see how close this is to what you're looking for.

Comment: @Martin Gal exactly. it is something like this

Comment: @Ottie thanks. Actually, I've been trying this hader way since it is quite difficult for me to understand what I am supposed to correct through this code. It is a kind of exercise